# Leaderboard.map is not a function when trying to create a levels leaderboard

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get a leaderboard for XP/levels up and running (with the data stored in mongoDB) and keep getting this typeError (leaderboard.map is not a function) whenever I run the command.

I'm able to check the levels using a !rank command, but run into issues with the !leaderboard command.

My leaderboard code is:

```
    if(command === "leaderboard" || command === "lb") {
        const rawLeaderboard = await Levels.fetchLeaderboard(message.guild.id, 5);
        if (rawLeaderboard.length < 1) return reply("PandaBot says nobody's in leaderboard yet! ");

        const leaderboard = Levels.computeLeaderboard(client, rawLeaderboard); 

        const lb = leaderboard.map(e => `${e.position}. ${e.username}#${e.discriminator}\nLevel: ${e.level}\nXP: ${e.xp.toLocaleString()}`);

        message.channel.send(`${lb.join("\n\n")}}`)
    }
```

All I can think of is changing it to `await leaderboard.map` but I won't have access to the computer to test it for a while.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I did a console.log(leaderboard) underneath that code and got back
```Promise {
  [
    {
      guildID: '764347249495900170',
      userID: '673743545974128640',
      xp: 399,
      level: 1,
      position: 1,
      username: 'pandachu',
      discriminator: '2095'
    }
  ]
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Levels.computeLeaderboard(client, rawLeaderboard)` returns a promise so you either need to use `.then()` or `await` to get the result:

```js
const leaderboard = await Levels.computeLeaderboard(client, rawLeaderboard);
const lb = leaderboard.map(
  (e) =>
    `${e.position}. ${e.username}#${e.discriminator}\nLevel: ${
      e.level
    }\nXP: ${e.xp.toLocaleString()}`,
);

message.channel.send(lb.join('\n\n'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Added await Levels.computeLeaderboard and it worked